# Using Backbone.js in SaaS without templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view, saas

I am designing a SaaS application and have been directed to Backbone.js. The service in part tracks DOM events such as how many of each have occurred and then applies scores based on this information.

Decoupling data into Models and Collections is very appealing, but before I go any deeper I want to enquire as to whether it is the right tool for the job.

I want to work with existing DOM elements written in the HTML of a site owners page rather than create JavaScript templates. I will therefore be tracking DOM events on existing elements which then update the data model. The site owner making use of the service will then be able to use the data in the Model to create their own Views and render their own templates specific to their needs.

I understand that I will need to use Backbone.View to track the events, and from what I have read so far it seems [Backbone has the flexibility](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/) to allow this. However, I haven’t seen any examples in my research of Backbone used to track a bunch of events on a number of form elements.

Take this code for example:

```
App.Models.Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        clicks: 0,
        dblClicks: 0,
        tabs: 0,
        kbdFunctions: 0
    },

    urlRoot: 'events'
});

App.Views.Event = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new App.Models.Event(),

    events: {
        'click input' : 'clickCount',
        'dblclick input' : 'dblClickCount',
        'tabEvent input' : 'tabCount',
        'kbdEvent input' : 'kbdEventCount'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.el = $('[data-transaction=start]');
    },

    clickCount: function (e) {
        console.log('click counted');
    },

    dblClickCount: function (e) {
        console.log('double click counted');
    },

    tabCount: function (e) {
        console.log('tab counted');
    },

    kbdEventCount: function (e) {
        console.log('keyboard event counted');
    }
});
```

I want to be able to track clicks, double clicks, tabs and other custom keyboard events that occur on `input`, `textarea`, `select` options and `button` that are contained within the `[data-transaction=start]` element. Firstly, is this an applicable use case for Backbone, and secondly, if so what is the best way of adding multiple elements within the Backbone.View events object literals? I haven't seen any examples of this in the documentation or anywhere else, but it would be good if I could add a variable into this like:

```
...
var someVariable = input, textarea, select, button;

events: {
    'click someVariable' : 'clickCount',
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are assigned by Backbone using the `delegateEvents` method in view. This method is called AFTER your view initialize method ([code reference](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-119))

so you could pass your variables in view constructor

```
myView = new App.Views.Events ( someVariable )
```

in your initialize method, you can assign events:

```
initialize: function(someVariable) {
    //assign this.events from someVariable as you would like

}
```

**EDIT:**

just read in Backbone documentation:

> The **events** property may also be defined as a function that returns an
>   events hash, to make it easier to programmatically define your events,
>   as well as inherit them from parent views.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you mind elaborating on assigning this.events from someVariable as you would like within initialize? I have http://jsfiddle.net/6KA84/ at the moment and can't get the clickCount function to fire.

Comment: check this > http://jsfiddle.net/9DUAz/ . Also I've made a slight edit to the answer